# Can't make a Stand alone exe in VFP9

Tags: visual-foxpro

I can't make a Stand alone exe file in VFP9.  I have tried the following codes.

`BUILD PROJECT XX FROM MAIN
BUILD EXE MAINEXE FROM XX`

It will make an executable file.  But its not a Stand alone.  Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "stand alone"?

Comment: Means... which should be work anywhere without any supporting file.

Comment: Then no. At the very least any VFP program requires the corresponding VFP runtime to be present, and then any additional files specific to your usage. Why it's so important? You just have to copy a few more files in addition to the exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot make an executable with VFP that would run without any runtime files. All you need is to add those few DLLs (listed below) to your executable's folder (if you don't have any other dependencies like FLLs, activex):

Vfp9r.dll
Vfp9t.dll
Vfp9Renu.dll

Note: If you think about it, that is the case with many languages out there. There are not so many languages where you can build native all-in-one executables (C, Go as examples).

Comment: Its helped me a lot.  Thank you Cetin...

In the earlier versions of Foxpro (I mean Dos version),  we can make Stand alone EXE with `BUILD EXE MAINEXE FROM XX EXTEND`

Comment: Is there any windows version of Foxpro, to make stand alone exe?

Comment: AFAIK no. It was only possible in FPDOS 2.6 and earlier. As I said, most of the languages that are in wide use doesn't have such standalone executables (C#, Vb for example).

Comment: What about Foxpro 2.x for Windows?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember FPW that much (in those days I were leaning towards creating DOS apps only). If you just drop those 3 DLLs in the same folder as your executable, it would be like a standalone. I wouldn't be concerned about that much (and you would be granted with new stuff available in VFP - and lose 1-2 things that were possible in FP2.x).